# producing a grid of results in R

Tags: r

I am writing some code to do a maximum likelihood estimation of some parameter values, and I am trying to create a surface plot of parameter values taken from the optim function, and need to create a grid to do so. It is the part whereby I need to create a grid that is confounding me,
My MLE function looks like:

```
loglike<-function(par,dat,scale)
{ ptp<-dat[1:length(dat)-1]
  ptp1<-dat[2:length(dat)]

  r<-par['r']
  k<-par['k']
  sigma<-par['sigma']

  if(scale=='log')
  {
    return(sum(dnorm(log(ptp1)-log(ptp)*exp(r-(ptp/k)),mean=0,sd=sigma,log=T)))
  }

  if (scale=='sqrt')
  {
    return(sum(dnorm(sqrt(ptp1)-sqrt(ptp)*exp(r-(ptp/k)),mean=0,sd=sigma,log=T)))
  }

  if (scale=='linear')
  {
    return(sum(dnorm(ptp1-ptp*exp(r-(ptp/k)),mean=0,sd=sigma,log=T)))
  }
}
```

I have already created some data from the optim giving me corresponding parameter values

I have tried taking  output from the optim function and putting it into the expand.grid function like:

```
gridlog<-expand.grid(logs[,"r"],logs[,"sigma"],logs[,"k"])
```

But all this is doing is creating a large matrix filled with all the same values.

Where the data going into the expand.grid function is filled from :

```
logs<-list()
for(i in seq(1,300,0.1)){
  logs[i]<-optim(par=c(r=i,k=i,sigma=i),fn=loglike,dat=dat,scale='log',method='Nelder-Mead',control=list(fnscale=-1))

}
logs<-do.call(rbind,logs)
```

This creates a 300 long matrix of corresponding sigma's r's and k's

My data is:

```
c(100, 128.675595618645, 75.436115414503, 146.398449792328, 102.419994706974, 
207.397726741841, 23.4579309898438, 42.4085746569567, 119.498216389673, 
59.7845591706614, 119.37201616882, 252.047672957539, 28.3165331949818, 
57.4918213065119, 311.615538092141, 8.53779749227741, 31.5382580618134, 
115.617013730077, 43.6907812963781, 70.9139870053552, 123.004040266686, 
132.575148404208, 114.813947981006, 115.950032495637, 120.891472762661, 
97.0207348527786, 235.618894638631, 17.0936655960759, 49.4419128844531, 
112.476950569973, 58.3241789008329, 80.0300102105128, 103.248819284132, 
99.1968765946717, 113.905769052605, 143.181386861766, 62.962989192695, 
174.054591300157, 39.9156352770331, 81.8344415290292, 176.631480374326, 
51.5564038694108, 131.542259464434, 72.5981749979889, 38.9733086158719, 
126.808054274927, 73.6960412245896, 62.5484608101147, 55.539355637003, 
137.888502803112, 106.921926717155, 140.000738390606, 162.512046122238, 
26.2949484171288, 80.4110888678422, 74.0481779531392, 33.9890286552257, 
142.477859644323, 55.1820570626643, 107.242498924143, 56.8497685792794, 
143.676120209843, 84.2334844367379, 67.0330079913484, 109.96246704725, 
157.216290273118, 59.4585552091703, 67.2986524284706, 55.2529503291083, 
38.932960005221, 62.7454169122216, 210.687014199037, 38.7348882392115, 
75.6645116341029, 115.924283193145, 117.772958122253, 45.5313134644358, 
112.306998515583, 38.7001172906923, 66.1308507048062, 122.516808638813, 
38.8283932430479, 168.014298040365, 38.0902373313928, 117.414876109978, 
168.615976661456, 66.5037228223079, 94.4482610053865, 505.254990783834, 
1.05181785078369, 1.77594058056118, 4.36034444400473, 12.1485473106491, 
82.2373017835424, 58.9775202042162, 132.907299665772, 51.2346939236555, 
123.251093218535, 143.077217943039, 96.1524852870813)
```

Any help anyone could give would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `gridlog<-expand.grid(logs[,"r"],logs[,"sigma"],logs[,"k"])` works perfectly well for me (granted that I tried only with a `logs` of 30 values instead of 300). FYI the 0.1 in `for i in seq(1,300,0.1)` is useless since you can't index with a decimal value. That's why, by the way, you have a `logs` of  300 rows instead of a `logs` with 2991 as you should have had with `seq(1,300,0.1)`. The results contained in `logs` are the results given for every i in `seq(1,300,1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#find optimum:
fit<-optim(par=c(r=1,k=1,sigma=1),fn=loglike,dat=dat,scale='log',
           method='Nelder-Mead',control=list(fnscale=-1))

fit$par
        r           k       sigma 
0.3911590 254.4989317   0.5159761 

# make grid around optimum with few selected sigma values:

rs<-seq(0.01,1,length=30)
ks<-seq(230,280,length=30)
sigmas<-c(0.25,0.5159761,0.75)

# this will contains all parameter combinations 
# and the corresponding likelihood values

mlegrid<-cbind(as.matrix(expand.grid(rs,ks,sigmas)),0)  #Matrix
colnames(mlegrid)<-c('r','k','sigma','likelihood')

for(i in 1:nrow(mlegrid)){ #go through all combinations
  mlegrid[i,4]<- loglike(par=mlegrid[i,1:3],dat=dat,scale='log') 
}
mlegrid[which.max(mlegrid[,4]),] 
      r           k       sigma  likelihood 
0.3855172 257.5862069   0.5159761 -74.9940496 
# almost the same as from optim 
# (differences due to sparse grid, more dense gives more accurate results)

#for interactive plots, static versions with `persp` function
library(rgl)
persp3d(x=rs,y=ks,
        z=matrix(mlegrid[mlegrid[,3]==sigmas[1],4],nrow=length(rs)),col=2)
#with sigma from optim
persp3d(x=rs,y=ks,
        z=matrix(mlegrid[mlegrid[,3]==sigmas[2],4],nrow=length(rs)),col=2) 
persp3d(x=rs,y=ks,
        z=matrix(mlegrid[mlegrid[,3]==sigmas[3],4],nrow=length(rs)),col=2)
```

Comment: I've just been able to try this and the fourth column of the mlegrid isn't being filled by the likelihood values.

Comment: No it just creates the mlegrid but the fourth column, "likelihood" is filled with 0's.

Comment: It creates a matrix with all the combinations of r k and sigma specified, but no value in the likelihood column of the matrix. I would guess that it's not actually putting values into the likelihood function.

Comment: Now with the latest edit it produces error "dnorm(x, mean, sd, log) : 
  Non-numeric argument to mathematical function." So I understand that it is passing symbols rather than the value entries of the mlegrid

Comment: Okay I've just tried plotting it and I'm getting error message "  "increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected." I'm also not sure that the function  loglike function is having values passed to it properly as I'm getting very strange likelihood values.
Have you tried running the original code? That seems to return more probably likelihood values than what you have posted.

Comment: Okay I will post the data. I know what I want, a surface that shows how the likelihood changes with the different parameter values r and k for a specified sigma, a graphical display of the different likelihoods for the parameter combinations.

Comment: Okay I tried what you have run but my previous attempt is still giving me much more sensible likelihood and parameter values. At this stage I think I'm just going to stick with my original approach but thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: The code you wrote is sensitive to any values of r and k, it just shows the highest likelihood as being the one corresponding to the highest value of r and k you allow for.
The - sign in "fnscale=-1" finds the maximum value not the minimum.

Comment: Oh yes the minus sign in my code was an error, my plot is for minus loglikelihood, the bottom is the best value.`mlegrid[which.min(mlegrid[,4]),] r k sigma likelihood 0.3855172 257.5862069 0.5159761 74.9940496` which is the same as the one obtained from the optim, ie the best value.

Comment: Your code also has the problem of being stuck in the local optimum as you only pass a single set of starting values to optim.

Comment: You can extend the search region by changing the grid coordinates rs,ks, and sigma, I just tested with some values as an example. Your original code doesn't provide necessary values for grid, but you can use it for finding the maximum and then use my code for drawing grid around that point.